# C# 2D Enemy Follow Y Axis Only While Rotating to Look At Player (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity, 2d

I have a 2D game where the player can move up and down on the y axis, I need the enemy to rotate to look at my player (which I have working, but probably isn't the best method) while also moving up and down with the player.

I have both of those things working, but not fully, right now whenever I move up and down, the rotation happening seems to cause the enemy to move backwards more and more with each up and down movement.

I need it to remain stationary on the x and z axis's.

Also, if anyone knows how I could make it so the enemy always wants to be slightly above the player on the y axis, that'd be awesome. Meaning, instead of locking onto the player dead straight, maybe the enemy can be up slightly by perhaps 20%.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
public float moveSpeed = 3.0f;
public Transform target;

private Transform myTransform;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
  myTransform = transform;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
  Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(
    target.transform.position - transform.position, 
    transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.up));
  transform.rotation = new Quaternion(0, 0, rotation.z, rotation.w);

  if (target.transform.position.y < myTransform.position.y)  {

    myTransform.position -= myTransform.up * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime; 
  }
  else if (target.transform.position.y > myTransform.position.y) {

    myTransform.position += myTransform.up * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime; 
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a video or a couple of images that illustrate your issue, and, if at all possible, images of what you expect. This would help us help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float YOffset = 0f;

void Update() 
{
    myTransform.LookAt(target);
    float targetPosY = target.transform.position.y + YOffset;
    if(myTransform.position.y != targetPosY)
    {
        float MoveAmount = moveSpeed * Time.delta;
        if(Mathf.Abs(myTransform.position.y - targetPosY) < MoveAmount)
            myTransform.position = Vector3.up * MoveAmount;
        else
        {
            if (targetPosY < myTransform.position.y)  
            {
                myTransform.position -= Vector3.up * MoveAmount; 
            }
            else if (targetPosY > myTransform.position.y) 
            {
                myTransform.position += Vector3.up * MoveAmount; 
            }
        }
    }
```

}

1.) Consider using [Transform.LookAt](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) to simplify the rotation.

2.) In your movement code, myTransform.Up represents the Up vector of the transform in local spcae, so if your model is tipped off center then Up will no longer point Up in world space. Use Vector3.Up as MistaGiggles suggests.

3.) You can make your enemy hover above the player by adding an Offset amount for the Y axis like the sample code above.

Additional way to rotate your enemy based on your comment:

1.) Get the normalized vector from enemy to player and assign it to Transform.Right, which would be your X axis. Unity takes care of updating the Transform's rotation internally when you set Up/Right/Forward manually.

```
    Vector2 lookDir = (target.transform.position - myTransform.position); 
    myTransform.right = lookDir; 
    if ((target.transform.position.y + YOffset) < myTransform.position.y) 
    {
        float MovementAmount = moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if((myTransform.position.y - MovementAmount) < (target.transform.position.y + YOffset))
        {
            myTransform.position = new Vector3(myTransform.position.x,target.transform.position.y + YOffset, myTransform.position.z);
        }
        else  
            myTransform.position -= Vector3.up * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime; 
    } 
    else if ((target.transform.position.y + YOffset) > myTransform.position.y) 
    { 
        float MovementAmount = moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if((myTransform.position.y + MovementAmount) > (target.transform.position.y + YOffset))
        {
            myTransform.position = new Vector3(myTransform.position.x,target.transform.position.y + YOffset, myTransform.position.z);
        }
        else
            myTransform.position += Vector3.up * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime; 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jeremiah, I really appreciate the help! - That code works quite well, thank you! - Only I'm not sure how to get it to face the direction of the character now, at the moment it turns itself to facing the camera (so it looks thin), I need it to face my character who is to the right of the enemy on the x axis. And the rotation needs to be on the z axis. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, I'm sorry for how disgusting the above comment is, apparently if you press enter to make a new paragraph, it just sends the comment.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Jeremiah, where would I place this code in your script you posted the first time?

Comment: Never mind, I worked it out actually, thanks! - Do you perhaps know how I can stop the enemy from jittering up and down when the player is just falling from gravity (no keys pressed). I think it's due to the enemy trying to rotate towards the player, but since the player is already level with the enemy, it won't let him.

Comment: Also, I've just spotted another issue. Right now my enemy is getting "squashed" slightly, he's being rotated on more than just the z axis, his y and x axis' both keep changing and I need to try to 'lock' them, so they don't get affected.

Comment: Alright, never mind that last 'squash' issue, I resolved it by using a Vector2 instead of 3. I still have that jittering problem though, any ideas?

Comment: I'm on my phone so its hard to enter an example but its because of Ur movement code I believe. The enemy moves Speed*Timedelta, but what if its less then that from being even? So it moves past to far and next frame again moves Speed*Time.deltaTime back the other way and so on. You need to add a check to see if the distance needed to move is less then speed*Time.deltaTime and if true then just move that amount.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot, I'll try to work out what you're saying for now, I don't hold much hope for myself here though. If you have a chance when you're on your PC, do you suppose you could show me an example or the correct code necessary?

Comment: Updated the answer to take into account distances smaller then moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime.

Comment: Thanks Jeremiah, I ran into an issue though, I used your code and it's giving me an error, I've looked that issue up but I don't know how to fix it pertaining to my specific problem. It's on this line myTransform.position.y = MoveAmount; - and it gives me this error - Assets/FollowPlayer.cs(28,45): error CS1612: Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.Transform.position'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable

Comment: My bad. Unity won't allow you to modify single members of the position vector, you have to assign to it all at the same time so just change it to:   myTransform.position = Vector3.up * MoveAmount;

Comment: Alright, I get it now. But when I used it this time, it completely vanished. I'm not sure where it goes, it may be turning sideways again but in a manner where I can't see it this time. I've changed the look at part to be the solution you posted earlier, now it's upside down and following my player on the right side of him instead of the left. I'm going to move this to chat so I can show you the code I have. Edit: Scratch that, not enough Rep.

Comment: Maybe just change it back to the "jittering" code that worked properly then add the check to see if the distance it needs to move is less then Speed * Time.deltaTime, and if so then just place it at the correct position rather then moving the entire (Speed * Time.deltaTime) distance.

Comment: Alright, I've done that, I'm not entirely sure how to do it though, I've tried some methods but obviously I'm not doing it right. Here is the code: 'Vector2 lookDir = (target.transform.position - myTransform.position);
  myTransform.right = lookDir;


  if ((target.transform.position.y + YOffset * Time.deltaTime) < myTransform.position.y)  
  {
   myTransform.position -= Vector3.up * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime; 
  }
  else if ((target.transform.position.y + YOffset * Time.deltaTime) > myTransform.position.y) 
  {
   myTransform.position += Vector3.up * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime; 
  }
 }'

Comment: Updated code at the bottom of the answer. Should be something like that if I understand your problem. I tried to make it easy to read but you could optimize it some once you have it working....

Comment: Amazing, that worked perfectly, thank you so much for all the help here Jeremiah! - I appreciate that so much, I would up-vote your answer if I could but I need more rep, so I've just accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why have a private member "myTransform" and then mix usage of "transform" and "myTransform"? It is more readable to just use "transform".

I have a feeling that the problem arises from using "myTransform.up" vs "Vector3.up" combined with your rotation code. I think the combination of the quaternion calculations and the local up vector is resulting in an accumulated offset in the axis you want to remain unchanged.

Have a look at [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) for calculating the rotation (you may need to offset the result).

Alternatively make use of Euler angles, as you are only working with one axis of rotation (where you have no benefit of using quaternions over euler angles).

As for moving backwards, if you are working in the global y-axis, use "Vector3.up" (which is global up) vs "myTransform.up" which is the up direction of your object after rotation is taken into account (and so will change direction depending on where it is looking).

Comment: Thanks for the help MistaGiggles, I'm looking into vector3.up now for future use, I wasn't aware that both were viable for this purpose and that one is better than the other.